# How to fix error "Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'" when parse xml file?

Tags: php, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SimpleXML Reading node with a hyphenated name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626901/simplexml-reading-node-with-a-hyphenated-name)

I parse xml file which contain fields like that:

```
<offers>
    <offer>
       <type>Vehicle</type>
       <type-id>2</type-id>
       <category>Car</category>
       <category-id>3</category-id>
       ...
    </offer>
    <offer>
       <type>Vehicle</type>
       <type-id>2</type-id>
       <category>Car</category>
       <category-id>3</category-id>
       ...
    </offer>
    ...
</offers>
```

Use `$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);` first and after trying to get values in foreach loop I get error "Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'"  for field contain 'id' as part of them, like 'type-id' or 'category-id'

```
 foreach($xml->offers->offer as $offer) {
                    echo $offer->type; // WORKS JUST FINE
                echo $offer->type-id; //THIS GIVE ME ERROR                              
              }
```

I trying to set `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);` but after it field with 'id' return zero instead of value.

Comment: To access values that have `-` inside of them, you need to put them into brackets as string: `echo $offer->{'type-id'};`

Comment: Yes, I found it `echo $offer->{'type-id'};` works.

Comment: More info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214153/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-object-operator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the variable is "type-id", which cannot be written simply as $type-id, you need to use curly brackets to access it: ${"type-id"}

```
echo $offer->{"type-id"};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
foreach($xml->offers->offer as $offer) {
    echo $offer->type;
    $typeId = 'type-id';
    echo $offer->{$typeId};                        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to access the object/variable using { and }

```
echo $offer->{type-id};
```

Comment: This will subtract two undefined constants, "type" and "id", and use the result as a field name